# Which is the best way to bend a rod

Tags: mesh

[image]

What is the simplest way to bend a plain rod (subdivided cylinder) and give it a U-shape (for instance) ?

Here is a solution: As suggested by cegaton best option is using Warp (not Bend) with cursor on symmetry axis (distance gives radius) and 90° offset. Straight plain rod is changed to round rod with no deformation.

[image]

Comment: As suggested by cegaton best option is using Warp (not Bend) with cursor on symmetry axis (distance gives radius) and 90° offset. Straight plain rod is changed to round rod with no deformation.